# console version of sysinfo

Tags: 12.04

Is there a console, text-only version of the [sysinfo](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-get-your-system-information-with-sysinfo.html) program or other similar utility? I am mostly interested in high-level info like RAM and CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lshw` should be what you are looking for.